# Adding Facebook sdk and cwac to Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm having gradle issues saying:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

While most people have pointed toward a fault in my library hierarchy and settings.gradle, I believe the issue is much simpler: **I haven't downloaded the Facebook sdk which my gradle expects.**

I downloaded this project from github and it comes with three folders in the libs directory, called cwac, Facebook, utils and, estimate-sdk-preview.jar. Here is a general look at the project hierarchy.

```
root
    .idea
    app
       libs
           cwac
               cwac.iml
           fb
               fb.iml
           utils
               utils.iml
           estimote-sdk-preview.jar
        src
         … all source files
    gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
External Libraries
    Android API 20 Platform
    JDK
```

Being new to Android Studio Projects I have no idea how to configure this newly downloaded project such that all of these libraries are working. Do I have to re-download the sdk? And if I do how do I point this correctly at it? What are iml files? Just in case you don't believe that my settings.gradle is good, here's a look at it:

```
include ':app', ':facebook', ':cwac', ':utils'
project(':facebook').projectDir = new File('app/libs/facebook')
project(':cwac').projectDir = new File('app/libs/cwac')
project(':utils').projectDir = new File('app/libs/utils')
```

So far I have attempted deleting the Facebook folder under libs and trying to add the Facebook project folder from the sdk, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. Also any idea about the other library folders? I don't know what additional files I need to download. THe original creator of the project told me I need the Facebook sdk and cwac camera sdk. Please help, I'm really lost, and I need to get this going fast.

EDIT: Run on the command line still fails:

> ./gradlew assembleDebug
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>     Configuration with name 'default' not found.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get >more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.546 secs
>   Arjunas-MacBook-Air:midnight-android Arjuna$

Stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:493)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:80)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.UnknownConfigurationException: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.createNotFoundException(DefaultConfigurationContainer.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.getByName(DefaultConfigurationContainer.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.getProjectConfiguration(DefaultProjectDependency.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency_Decorated.getProjectConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:153)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.getProperty(BeanDynamicObject.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_ensureConfigured_closure158.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:2473)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureConfigured(BasePlugin.groovy:2471)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy:2389)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.this$2$resolveDependencyForConfig(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$this$2$resolveDependencyForConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.resolveDependencies(BasePlugin.groovy:2308)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForDefaultBuild(VariantManager.java:311)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:169)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$createAndroidTasks.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:427)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_apply_closure7.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:338)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:83)
    at org.gradle.listener.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:31)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: "I downloaded this project" -- what is "this project"?

Comment: Does it build from the command line?

Comment: Its a private project I volunteered to work on at work. And I haven't tried from the command line but why would that work if I haven't even downloaded the proper sdks?

Comment: I'm thinking that it's having a problem with the relative paths you're using in settings.gradle -- you're relying on the working directory being set to the project root when you build from Android Studio, which isn't the case. Often times if you build from the command line it does work because you build from project root. This would explain your "configuration with name 'default' not found". I didn't catch that when you asked the same question before.

Comment: I put up the stack trace from running on command line.

Comment: I think in general you're having trouble understanding how Gradle works (and it's not your fault -- Gradle is very tricky), and trying to get a complex project working as your first experience isn't serving you well. You might be better off starting with a multi-module Android Studio project created via the New Project and New Module wizards, studying that to see how the pieces fit together, and then slowly trying to graft new pieces on to it. That way you're starting with something that works and are changing one thing at a time.

Comment: So you don't think I need to download any sdks? I assumed that this project would have its gradle well configured, and from what I can tell looking at it…it is in fact well configured. The only reason why a well formed project wouldn't work on my system is because I do not have something it is looking for in the correct location. I have to assume that this isn't an uncommon to download a project and see this issue.